# Replace all ↵ for a new line in angular loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a loop currently in my application located here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="audit in audctrl.audits | orderBy:'-created_at'">
  <td>
    {{audit.objects}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

The object's code shows a lot of text, but with a lot of the ↵ symbol.

How would I go about making these replaced?

I have tried

```
{{audit.object.replace(/\u21B5/g,'<br/>')}}
```

What would be the best method to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to write an **angular filter**. For example:

```
myApp.filter('multiline', function () {
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    }
});
```

and then call it with pipe:

```
<tr ng-repeat="audit in audctrl.audits | orderBy:'-created_at'">
  <td>
    {{audit.objects | multiline}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

@Edit
I'm not sure about your new line character code but you can easy change it. Angular filters are good because they are reusable in other parts of application.

@Edit2 
To display html tags in Angular binding u have to use `$sce` service and `ng-bind-html="audit.objects | multiline"` instead of `{{audit.objects | multiline}}`

http://jsfiddle.net/c1qwg776/

Comment: Hey Karol, I've been working on this the second you posted this, I ran into a small issue, besides being able to find the code for the enter key i changed the enter key to a ':' and this only replaced the first colon even there there are multiple?

Comment: Hmm.. regular expression should find and replace all characters. Please check jsfiddle I have added to my answer.

Comment: How annoying, I've copied almost all your code and i have the same issue, Weird... going to mark as correct because this does work, something must be messing with my code

Comment: You need to use `/\n/g` to replace all. `/` in the beginning and `/g` at the end is of great importance.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your controller at initialisation:

```
for(var i=0;i<audctrl.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<audctrl[i].objects.length;j++){
        if(audctrl[i].objects.charCodeAt(j)===10){
            var temp=audctrl[i].objects.substring(0,j);
            temp+="<br/>";
            audctrl[i].objects= temp+audctrl[i].objects.substring(j+5,audctrl[i].objects.length-1);
        }
    }
}
```