# How to replace some character with space in AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs

I need to replace all special character with hyphen(-) with this name like (Inka -Tiitto-s-Camp-Aero-Gravity-Milan-9). But I am getting this error.

=> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
and also getting the name like this (Inka Tiitto's Camp @ Aero Gravity Milan -9)

I have tried this line of code but not getting desirable result.

```
<a href="<?= BASEURL ?>camp/{{x.name.split('/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()@\+\?><\[\]\+]/g').join('-')}}-{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</a>
```

Could anyone help me to get this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would advise not doing that kind of thing in the template; the best place is in the controller.

Comment: The best way to do this is to write a filter. Example code is in my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936111/replace-all-for-a-new-line-in-angular-loop/45936221#45936221

Comment: can you suggest how can i do it in controller? @rrd

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```
angular.module('filters')

.filter('replaceChars', function() {
  return function(value) {
    if(!value) {
      return '';
    }

    return value
      .toString()
      .replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()@\+\?><\[\]\+]/g, '-');
  };
});
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<a href="<?= BASEURL ?>camp/{{x.name | replaceChars}}-{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</a>
```